# Generic function type guard

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to check whether got a function or value here ?

```
function f<T>(valueOrFunction : T | (()=>T)) {
  if(typeof valueOrFunction === "function" ) {
   //  Got a function
  } else {
   // Still 'T | (()=>T)'
   // Wanted: to get 'T'.
  }
}
```

Comment: what is your expectation? read your post and see if it conveys enough information, if not update with relevant content

Answer (score 0):

Everything works as intended.
It was 'Resharper' which thinks the code is incorrect.

Comment: What if the type of `T` was a function?

Comment: I don't need it to be a function, I can live with this limitation.